# Translating 別として

Tags: grammar, translation, words, syntax

> ウソかホントかは**別として**、聞いたことあるその話。

Could someone help me translate this sentence? I tried but it sounds horrible, I don't know what is best way to translate 別として here. Thank you!

Comment: What was the translation you came up with?

Comment: 'Whether it is true or false, I've heard this story.' It sounds a bit weird to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your translation is really close!  You should probably be able to understand it if you took a look at the meaning of 別として [here.](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%88%A5%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6)  If not, the rest of the stuff I've written below should help you get the meaning in relation to how the grammar is working here.

This is a great sentence for learning the uses of か as well, and I think that is important to understand how the first part `ウソかホントかは` works before we get to the 別として part.  If you feel like you have a good understanding of `ウソかホントかは,` go ahead and skip the next paragraph, which I am including for context for the rest of my translation.

`ウソかホント` can be roughly translated as `lie or real` (i.e. `true or false`)  The second か here makes it an embedded question.  The part that gives this away is the は, which is the particle that every Japanese learner spends days trying to learn.

[別として](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%88%A5%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6) is defined by jisho.org to mean: `"other than; except for; aside from; apart from; save for​."` The way I personally understand the usage in your sentence is something to the effect of `"Regardless of whether or not this is true..."`   A literal translation here would be something like `"Apart from the question of if it's a lie, or real ... "`

The following would be my translation of your sentence:

> ウソかホントかは別として、聞いたことあるその話。
>
> Setting aside whether it's true or false, I have heard that story (as well).

I put the (as well) in parenthesis because while the sentence never directly said it, it seems like it is being implied.

Hope it helps.